# Randomising a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of data that contains a field `forename`. 
I need to make a copy of this table, but jumble up that column so that `forename` and `surname` no longer relate to a real person. 
Can anyone think of a way to natively do this in MySQL? I could program it in PHP but I don't think that's the most efficient way to achieve the goal..?

Comment: 'jumble up' ???

Comment: One possibility would be to create a table of forenames, and another of surnames. Both with unique keys. Then use the RANDOM function to select a row from each to update the new table.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many permutations you need, you can either make a new table and randomly join on them, or you can do it quickly inline as below:

```
UPDATE my_table SET forename =  
    ELT(1 + Floor(rand() * 10), /* 10 matches number of list items */
        "Sophia", "Jackson", "Emma", "Aiden", 
        "Olivia", "Lucas", "Ava", "Liam", "Mia", "Noah")
```